# Django regroup of cursor results

Tags: django, django-templates, cursor

Using Django, I have a fairly complex SQL query that is working fine and returning the results I want, so I am not keen to try to reproduce this using Django's model query notation.

I am passing my results to my template and am able to display them using the following notation:

`{% for line in myresults %}

    ...

    {{ line.0 }}

    ...

    {{ line.1 }}

    etc.

    {% endfor %}`

**Is there any way to use the regroup tag on this result set?**

If I try:

`{% regroup myresults by myresults.0 as mylist %}

    {% for item in mylist %}

    {{ item.grouper }}

    {% for line in item.list %}

    ...

    {{ line.0 }}

    {{ line.1 }}

    etc.`

I get all of the results as before (without any regrouping) but don't get the item.grouper (all I see is "None" as a single group rather than my multiple groups)

**Is this a syntax issue or am I trying something that doesn't fit regroup's capabilities?**

I have used regroup in the normal way with a list of objects, but the above has me stumped.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

with `{% regroup myresults by myresults.0 as mylist %}` you group by the first item in the list `myresults`  you must group by some field of the items.

Next example from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs):

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]
```

...and you'd like to display a hierarchical list that is ordered by country, like this:

```
India
    Mumbai: 19,000,000
    Calcutta: 15,000,000
USA
    New York: 20,000,000
    Chicago: 7,000,000
Japan
    Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

You can use the `{% regroup %}` tag to group the list of cities by country. The following snippet of template code would accomplish this:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in country.list %}
          <li>{{ item.name }}: {{ item.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```